# Why is specifying the POSITA skill set not practiced?

Tags: posita

The few patents I have reviewed do not address the ['POSITA'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_having_ordinary_skill_in_the_art) skill set.  For example, would it not be helpful / constructive to state that skill set should include:

- Bachelors of Science Electrical Engineering
- Experience with mixed signal simulation
- C++ and Python Programming
- TCP / IP Networking
- Relational Database Design

Why is  specifying the POSITA  skill set not practiced?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a very contentious issue.

As the applicant, it's impossible to guess what you'll need the skilled person to have. For example, you want them to have a high-degree of education and experience to be able to put your invention into practice, and fill any gaps in your description based on their broad knowledge. But you also want them to be a dunce, so that they can't consider any of your invention to be obvious based on their limited knowledge.

Until you know what is at issue in your particular case (or in other words, when you're in court on the day you're enforcing and defending your patent), you don't want to commit either way.

Comment: And because it's nothing *you* can define so whatever you do, best outcome nothing changes, worst outcome you shoot yourself.